# Error when creating a New Resource Group in Bicep using a Module

Tags: azure-bicep

I have a simple module to create a new Azure Resource Group:

The Module Code is:

```
targetScope='subscription'

param resourceGroupName string
param resourceGroupLocation string

resource newRG 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-01-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location: resourceGroupLocation
}
```

I then call the module from my main:

```
param SubscriptionID string = ''
param resourceGroupName string = 'rg-09'
param resourceGroupLocation string = 'westus3'

// module deployed to subscription
module newRG 'modules/rg.bicep' = {
  name: 'newResourceGroup'
  scope: subscription(SubscriptionID)
  params: {
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroupName
    resourceGroupLocation: resourceGroupLocation
  }
}
```

To execute the code I use:

New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -TemplateFile .\main_rg.bicep -Location 'westus3'

The error I get is:

New-AzDeployment: 11:34:18 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource 'newResourceGroup' at line '29' and column '9' is not valid: The template function 'RESOURCEGROUP' is not expected at this location. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-functions for usage details.. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-functions for usage details.'.

Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong

Comment: your main.bicep file should also have the `targetScope='subscription'`.

Comment: also you need to specify a value for the parameter `SubscriptionID`. You could set a default value like that: `param SubscriptionID string = subscription().subscriptionId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I also received the same error when I tried in my environment previously.*

[image]

After a workaround on this, I modified your code as below and was able to deploy successfully with `New-AzSubscriptionDeployment` command.

***Need to check:***

1. Once you added the target scope in `main.bicep` & `module.bicep`       then no need of adding the scope field separately in the code.
2. As @Thomas said, you need to add the `targetScope='subscription'` in each bicep file.

***main.bicep***:

```
targetScope='subscription'
param  resourceGroupName  string = 'rg-090'
param  resourceGroupLocation  string = 'eastus'
module  newRG  'module.bicep' = {
name: 'newResourceGroupcreate'
params: {
resourceGroupName: resourceGroupName
resourceGroupLocation: resourceGroupLocation
   }
}
```

***module.bicep:***

```
targetScope='subscription'
param  resourceGroupName  string
param  resourceGroupLocation  string
resource  newRG  'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-01-01' = {
name: resourceGroupName
location: resourceGroupLocation
}
```

***main.parameters.json:***

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"resourceGroupName": {
"value": "rg-090"
},
"resourceGroupLocation": {
"value": "eastus"
    }
  }
}
```

***Deployed with*** `New-AzSubscriptionDeployment`:

```
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment `
 -Location "westus3" `
 -TemplateFile ".\main.bicep" `
 -TemplateParameterFile ".\main.parameters.json"
```

[image]

[image]

Refer bicep template in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli).